# PHP MySQL JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, json

I am trying take data from a MySQL table and create a JSON output in the below format.

```
{
    markers: [
    {
       latitude: 57.7973333,
       longitude: 12.0502107,
       title: "Angered",
       content: "Representing :)"
    },
    {
       latitude: 57.6969943,
       longitude: 11.9865,
       title: "Gothenburg",
       content: "Swedens second largest city"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the PHP I am using to generate the JSON

```
$model  = array();

    $query = "SELECT title, content, lat, lng FROM locations_tbl";

    //Get records from database
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $model['title'][]       = $e['title'];
            $model['content'][] = $e['content'];
            $model['lat'][]     = $e['lat'];
            $model['lng'][]     = $e['lng'];
        }
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode(array('marker'=>$model));
```

Below is the output that I get with the above code:

```
{
   marker: {
      title: [
          "Marker 1",
          "Marker 2",
          "Marker 3",
          "Marker 4",
          "Marker 5"
       ],
       content: [
          "Text 1",
          "Text 2",
          "Text 3",
          "Text 4",
          "Text 5"
       ],
       lat: [
          "46.99065400",
          "47.03520400",
          "47.20387700",
          "47.62574900",
          "47.43443400"
       ],
       lng: [
          "-122.92164800",
          "-122.81614600",
          "-122.24486400",
          "-122.14453800",
          "-122.46088200"
       ]
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2495292 Your JSON is not valid, you can use this validator to to see validity http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I corrected your JSON, check if this is right JSON? http://pastebin.com/BeLxGZKy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array like this :

```
    $i = 0;
    while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $model[$i]['title']       = $e['title'];
        $model[$i]['content']     = $e['content'];
        $model[$i]['lat']         = $e['lat'];
        $model[$i]['lng']         = $e['lng'];
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
       $i = 0;
       while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $model[$i]['title']       = $e['title'];
            $model[$i]['content'] = $e['content'];
            $model[$i]['lat']     = $e['lat'];
            $model[$i]['lng']     = $e['lng'];
            $i++;
        }
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

You never actually create a new array for every marker:

```
$model = array("markers" => array());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $marker = array();
        $marker['title']    = $e['title'];
        $marker['content']  = $e['content'];
        $marker['lat']      = $e['lat'];
        $marker['lng']      = $e['lng'];
        $model["markers"][] = $marker;
    }
}
```